# comparing structure variable with a string

Tags: c++

I have to compare 2 strings, one is from a structure member and the other is "Empty".

I use `strcmp` like so:

```
if (strcmp(e[n]->seat[seat/5][(seat%5)-1], "Empty")==0)
```

I am getting the error `Invalid conversion from char to const char*`.

Can someone please help me out with this?

Comment: Just *try* a `&` before `e[n]`. Difficult to know for sure without more code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like e is an array of structures each containing a 3 deminsional character array. You should probably be using a two deminsional char pointer array unless you /know/ the string length won't change but if you don't just use the address like chnossos said.

```
if (strcmp(&(e[n]->seat[seat/5][(seat%5)-1]), "Empty")==0)
```